# how does cairngorm+flex integrate with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-flex, model-view-controller, cairngorm

I mean, the mvc for cairngorm and the one in rails don't overlap their functionalities? I'm not sure I understand the need for cairngorm with the rails backend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need, it's an option, Cairgorm see's the whole Rails as a model. Rails send xml instead of html so no browser-css-details headaches.

You can use rails as a REST layer and put your business logic in flex.

You can use cairgorm as a candy cover over a complex but well tested rails application.

You can find middle of the way solution that suits to you.

We do implement most business logic in rails but use flex/cairgorm to show each user only the right buttons/forms/controls to her task, and to do it in a nice browser-independent way.

Hope this helps you, feel free to ask any detail

Answer (score -1):

Rails is MVC for the server. You still need an architecture for a sufficiently complex client application. We're using PureMVC on the client with a REST (JSON) interface to a Rails server and it's working nicely. PureMVC allows for the client's model to be independent from the client's view components, and makes it easy to update independent view components simultaneously.